# Can't build an included file, using texstudio

Tags: compiling, thesis, include

I'm doing my thesis in `LaTeX`, and have multiple chapters, separated in different .tex files and included in the main.tex using `\include{}`, which worked normally, and I can build it, without returning to the main.tex file.

But after trying to start another chapter and build it directly, it shows the following error:

> `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % pone en TOC hasta la subsubsección
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % enumera hasta la subsubsección

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry} % margenes del documento
\geometry{letterpaper, top = {2,5cm}, bottom = {2,5cm}, inner = {2,5cm},
outer = {2,5cm}, head = {1,1cm}, foot = {1,1cm}, bindingoffset = {1,0cm}}
% Si se va a usar dos paginas por hoja, agregar la opción twoside

\usepackage{helvet} % Arial
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Arial

\usepackage{titlesec} % cambiar modo de ver capitulos y secciones
\titleformat{\chapter}[display] 
{\large\bfseries\centering}{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}{} % Cambios en Capitulo

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSección

\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection.}{1em}{\MakeUppercase} % Cambios en SubSubSección

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-2.5em}{3em} % Cambia el espaciamiento del capitulo de 50pt a lo pedido

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3em}{2em} % Cambia el espaciamiento de la sección a 3 espacios en blanco antes y 2 despues.

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[enumerate]{label=\thesection.\arabic*., leftmargin=*}

%\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\thechapter.\arabic{enumi}} % numero de capitulo en listas
%\renewcommand*{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumi}} % añade lo anterior a sublistas

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{section}[2em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[5em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2.9em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[9em]
    {\vspace{0em}}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{3.8em}\uppercase}
    {\hspace*{-2em}\uppercase}
    {\titlerule*[.75em]{.}\contentspage}
    

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} % interlineado de 1.5

\usepackage[skip=6pt, indent=1cm, tocskip]{parskip} % configurar espacio entre parrafos y sangría izquierda. tocskip genera el salto entre parrafos en el indice

% paquetes necesarios para citar
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites, url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{} % necesario para poner encabezado en paginas de capítulos

% paquete para encabezado y pie de pagina 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{
    \fancyfoot{}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum\value{page}<10 0\fi\arabic{page}}
}

\pagestyle{mystyle} % Aplicar el estilo de numeración de página personalizado

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} %% Formato de pies de foto

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

% - - - - - COMANDOS - - - - -
\newenvironment{itemizecita}{%
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\leftskip}{1.27cm}
    }{%
    \end{itemize}
}

\long\def\citalarga#1{%
    \medskip
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1
    \par
    \endgroup
    \medskip
}

\long\def\citalargacontinuacion#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 1.27cm
    \leftskip=1.27cm
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}

\long\def\resej#1{\medskip 
    \begingroup
    \parindent 0pt
    \leftskip=1.5em
    #1 \par \medskip
    \endgroup
}
% - - - - -  PORTADA - - - - -  

\title{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{text}}}
\author{text}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{2cm}

%% - - - - -  RESUMEN EJECUTIVO - - - - -  
%
\include{1-resumen-ejecutivo.tex} % works
%

\tableofcontents
% - - - - -  INTRODUCCIÓN - - - - -  

\clearpage % para que el siguiente comando empiece en una página nueva
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numeración en números arábigos
\include{2-introduccion.tex} % works

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 1  - - - - -  

\include{3-capitulo-1.tex} % works

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 2 - - - - -  

\include{4-capitulo-2.tex} % doesn't work

% - - - - -  CAPÍTULO 3  - - - - -  

\include{5-capitulo-3.tex}% doesn't work

% - - - - -  BIBLIOGRAFÍA - - - - -  

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

If I directly build the main.tex file, it shows the included chapters. Directly compiling until chapter-1.text works, but when trying to build 4-chapter-2.tex or 5-capitulo-3.tex it shows error.

Here are the log and file generated by the chapter that can't get build directly.

.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.3.10)  28 APR 2023 09:49
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**4-capitulo-2.tex
(./4-capitulo-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-10>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \chapter
            {aaa}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \chapter{a
              aa}
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--2
[] 
 []


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.3 a
     sdkaskdjaskd
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no j in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!

Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4
[] 
 []


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 a
     dasdasd
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no d in font nullfont!
)
! Emergency stop.
<*> 4-capitulo-2.tex
                    
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 17 strings out of 478238
 522 string characters out of 5850456
 289994 words of memory out of 5000000
 18355 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 13i,0n,12p,62b,18s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

.bgl:

```
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.19
[0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is '/home/jose-tomas/.cache/texstudio/archivos-temporales/4-capitulo-2.blg'
[76] biber:340> INFO - === vie abr 28, 2023, 09:49:56
[101] Utils.pm:410> ERROR - Cannot find '4-capitulo-2.bcf'!
[101] Biber.pm:136> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

.aux:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {3}aaa}{21}{chapter.3}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@setckpt{4-capitulo-2}{
\setcounter{page}{22}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\setcounter{enumii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiii}{0}
\setcounter{enumiv}{0}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\setcounter{mpfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\setcounter{subsubsection}{0}
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
\setcounter{subparagraph}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{tabx@nest}{0}
\setcounter{listtotal}{0}
\setcounter{listcount}{0}
\setcounter{liststart}{0}
\setcounter{liststop}{0}
\setcounter{citecount}{0}
\setcounter{citetotal}{0}
\setcounter{multicitecount}{0}
\setcounter{multicitetotal}{0}
\setcounter{instcount}{34}
\setcounter{maxnames}{2}
\setcounter{minnames}{1}
\setcounter{maxitems}{999}
\setcounter{minitems}{1}
\setcounter{citecounter}{0}
\setcounter{maxcitecounter}{0}
\setcounter{savedcitecounter}{0}
\setcounter{uniquelist}{0}
\setcounter{uniquename}{0}
\setcounter{refsection}{0}
\setcounter{refsegment}{0}
\setcounter{maxextratitle}{0}
\setcounter{maxextratitleyear}{0}
\setcounter{maxextraname}{2}
\setcounter{maxextradate}{0}
\setcounter{maxextraalpha}{0}
\setcounter{abbrvpenalty}{50}
\setcounter{highnamepenalty}{50}
\setcounter{lownamepenalty}{25}
\setcounter{maxparens}{3}
\setcounter{parenlevel}{0}
\setcounter{blx@maxsection}{0}
\setcounter{mincomprange}{10}
\setcounter{maxcomprange}{100000}
\setcounter{mincompwidth}{1}
\setcounter{afterword}{0}
\setcounter{savedafterword}{0}
\setcounter{annotator}{0}
\setcounter{savedannotator}{0}
\setcounter{author}{0}
\setcounter{savedauthor}{0}
\setcounter{bookauthor}{0}
\setcounter{savedbookauthor}{0}
\setcounter{commentator}{0}
\setcounter{savedcommentator}{0}
\setcounter{editor}{0}
\setcounter{savededitor}{0}
\setcounter{editora}{0}
\setcounter{savededitora}{0}
\setcounter{editorb}{0}
\setcounter{savededitorb}{0}
\setcounter{editorc}{0}
\setcounter{savededitorc}{0}
\setcounter{foreword}{0}
\setcounter{savedforeword}{0}
\setcounter{holder}{0}
\setcounter{savedholder}{0}
\setcounter{introduction}{0}
\setcounter{savedintroduction}{0}
\setcounter{namea}{0}
\setcounter{savednamea}{0}
\setcounter{nameb}{0}
\setcounter{savednameb}{0}
\setcounter{namec}{0}
\setcounter{savednamec}{0}
\setcounter{translator}{0}
\setcounter{savedtranslator}{0}
\setcounter{shortauthor}{0}
\setcounter{savedshortauthor}{0}
\setcounter{shorteditor}{0}
\setcounter{savedshorteditor}{0}
\setcounter{narrator}{0}
\setcounter{savednarrator}{0}
\setcounter{execproducer}{0}
\setcounter{savedexecproducer}{0}
\setcounter{execdirector}{0}
\setcounter{savedexecdirector}{0}
\setcounter{with}{0}
\setcounter{savedwith}{0}
\setcounter{labelname}{0}
\setcounter{savedlabelname}{0}
\setcounter{institution}{0}
\setcounter{savedinstitution}{0}
\setcounter{lista}{0}
\setcounter{savedlista}{0}
\setcounter{listb}{0}
\setcounter{savedlistb}{0}
\setcounter{listc}{0}
\setcounter{savedlistc}{0}
\setcounter{listd}{0}
\setcounter{savedlistd}{0}
\setcounter{liste}{0}
\setcounter{savedliste}{0}
\setcounter{listf}{0}
\setcounter{savedlistf}{0}
\setcounter{location}{0}
\setcounter{savedlocation}{0}
\setcounter{organization}{0}
\setcounter{savedorganization}{0}
\setcounter{origlocation}{0}
\setcounter{savedoriglocation}{0}
\setcounter{origpublisher}{0}
\setcounter{savedorigpublisher}{0}
\setcounter{publisher}{0}
\setcounter{savedpublisher}{0}
\setcounter{language}{0}
\setcounter{savedlanguage}{0}
\setcounter{origlanguage}{0}
\setcounter{savedoriglanguage}{0}
\setcounter{citation}{0}
\setcounter{savedcitation}{0}
\setcounter{pageref}{0}
\setcounter{savedpageref}{0}
\setcounter{textcitecount}{1}
\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}
\setcounter{textcitemaxnames}{0}
\setcounter{biburlbigbreakpenalty}{100}
\setcounter{biburlbreakpenalty}{200}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{0}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{0}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{0}
\setcounter{smartand}{0}
\setcounter{bbx:relatedcount}{0}
\setcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}{0}
\setcounter{caption@flags}{2}
\setcounter{continuedfloat}{0}
\setcounter{Item}{23}
\setcounter{Hfootnote}{0}
\setcounter{bookmark@seq@number}{19}
\setcounter{section@level}{0}
}
```

Comment: do not use external links show the full error from the log in a code block in the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will edit the post to add it

Comment: "But after trying to start another chapter and compile it directly,"  you can not use the included files as separate documents. or you would naturally get a missing `\begin{document}` error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Probably I should say "build".  I can build other included .tex files without any problem, and that's what I have been doing, but now it is showing error with newer chapters.

Comment: you show `*4-capitulo-2.tex(./4-capitulo-2.tex`  that can not possibly work, the file has no `\begin{document}`  as stated in the message.  It can not work for the other chapters either. If they work you are running latex on the main document not a chapter. Perhaps you have configured your editor to run the main document when running those chapters, you have not shown any relevant code so we can not say (and I can't help with texstudio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but after closing and opening again TeXstudio, now I can build the chapter without returning to the main.tex file.

I think it was probably some linking problem that got solved, by reloading the program.

Comment: With no identifiable cause or ability to reproduce, this is a candidate for closure.  I'll launch that.

Comment: If the problem does come back (i.e. stops being resolved) this can be reopened (assuming it gets closed), but you may be better off filing a bug report with the developers who should be better placed to help debug, diagnose, and fix.